# Как сделать из одной таблицы выборку в которой один и тот же столбец должен повторяться несколько раз?

Tags: sql-server

Есть таблица

> | дата отправления | отправитель |

Надо получить из неё выборку вот такого вида

> | отправитель | дата отправления | дата получения | получатель |

Comment: *Надо получить из неё выборку вот такого вида* На именно таких данных - никак. Ибо не видно критерия, по которому именно эта пара записей сведена в одну запись. Попробуйте его сформулировать... только не вздумайте ссылаться на "порядок записей", если не укажете при этом выражение сортировки.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @t table (datemessage datetime, id_tasks varchar(36), Whowritedmessage varchar(20));

insert into @t (datemessage, id_tasks, Whowritedmessage)
values 
('20171101 04:59:07', 'C56D5...', 'Client'),
('20171101 05:05:17', 'C56D5...', 'Client'),
('20171101 05:06:53', 'C56D5...', 'Agent'),
('20171101 05:06:53', 'C56D5...', 'Agent');


select 
A.Whowritedmessage as [ClientName],
A.datemessage as [ClientDate],
B.datemessage as [AgentDate], 
B.Whowritedmessage as [AgentName]
from 
(select top (1) C.datemessage, C.id_tasks, C.Whowritedmessage from @t C where C.Whowritedmessage = 'Client' order by C.datemessage) A 
INNER JOIN
(select top (1) C.datemessage, C.id_tasks, C.Whowritedmessage from @t C where C.Whowritedmessage = 'Agent' order by C.datemessage) B
ON A.id_tasks = B.id_tasks
WHERE 
    A.id_tasks = 'C56D5...'
```

Comment: Очевидно же, что в результате должно быть две записи, непонятно как связанных, но две `top (1)` здесь не годится

Comment: @DenisRubashkin Вовсе не очевидно. Как раз наоборот, логично предположить, что если бы в результате требовалось две записи, то обе они были приведены в желаемом результате. Пока что ответ (без дополнительных вводных) полностью соответствует формулировке вопроса.

Comment: @Yaant, не работает, выводит пустоту, сам также делал

Comment: @akuma А я-то тут причем? :) Код не мой, однако вполне рабочий: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/5bb2d/1

Comment: @Yaant, упс, не заметил) Но странно в MS Sql server пахать не хочет)

Comment: какие-то ошибки?

Comment: @Konst, ошибок нет, просто ничего не выводит

Comment: скрипт работает практически на ваших данных, может у вас они другие? исправьте тогда ваш вопрос, дополните его исходными значениями (не картинкой, а кодом)

Comment: @Konst, дополнил вопрос доп. входными данными и обновил скриншот того, что должно получится

Answer (score 0):

Если решать совсем в лоб, просто перекладывая на код "выбрать время первого ответа агента на сообщение клиента, перед которым не было других сообщений клиента" то:

```
;WITH MessagesWithFollowingAgentReplies AS
(
    SELECT cm.datemessage, am.datemessage as repl_date,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cm.id_tasks, cm.datemessage ORDER BY am.datemessage) rn_agent
    FROM DateMessage cm inner join DateMessage am on cm.id_tasks = am.id_tasks and cm.datemessage < am.datemessage
    WHERE cm.Whowritedmessage = 'Client' and am.Whowritedmessage = 'Agent'

),
NumberedForSameAgentReply AS
(
    SELECT datemessage, repl_date,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY repl_date ORDER BY datemessage) rn
    from MessagesWithFollowingAgentReplies where rn_agent = 1
)
SELECT 'Client', datemessage, repl_date, 'Agent' FROM NumberedForSameAgentReply WHERE rn = 1
```

Если аккуратно, и собеседников больше двух - то протаскивать колонки Whowritedmessage выше, добавляя их в PARTITION BY.

Comment: спасибо, но видимо у меня что-то с sql server'ом случилось ибо в sql fiddle твой код без проблем проходит, а у меня в sql server опять пустоту выводит) буду разбираться

Comment: @akuma Может вы не на той базе выбираете? Попробуйте дописывать запрос по шагам, проверьте, в какой момент данные пропадут

Comment: решил проблему)